# How to change the current selected option in the <select> by JS

Tags: javascript, html

I try a several ways to make it, but only what I got - two selected items in one time. Also I found on SOF a "solution" - `document.getElementById("selection-type").selectedIndex = 2;` , but it does not work.

I understand that this is a very simple question, but I really do not know what is I'am missed.

```js
  var select = document.body.querySelector('select');

  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
   if (select.options[i].selected) {
   }
  }

  select.options[1].selected = false;

  var newOption = new Option('Classic', 'Classic');
  select.append(newOption);

  select.options[2].selected = true;
```

```html
 <select>
   <option value="Rock">Storm</option>
   <option value="Blues" selected>Rain</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Your snippet appears to work perfectly

Comment: @SterlingArcher no-no-no. If you debug the code after start - you will see next `<select>
   <option value="Rock">Storm</option>
   <option value="Blues" selected="">Rain</option>
 <option value="Classic">Classic</option></select>` - still selected [1].element

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev The `selected` attribute controls only the default selected option, and *it does not change when a different option is selected by the user or via js*. To check that, you need to look at the `.selected` property of the DOM element, *not* the attribute.

Comment: The code 'as is' is working as expected on my machine.  'select.options[2].selected = true' is correctly causing the <select> to show 'Classic' as the active item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing attributes and properties. Changing a property is a dynamic action that affects the in-memory object, it doesn't modify the static HTML that the element was originally parsed with. If you want to change the attribute, you need to use `setAttribute()` or `removeAttribute()`.

```js
var select = document.body.querySelector('select');

// Get the element with the "selected" attribute
console.log("Element with 'selected' HTML attribute: " + 
   select.querySelector("[selected]").getAttribute("value"));

// Get the element with the "selected" value:
console.log("Element with value property of 'selected': " + select.value);

// Change the value property of the select
console.log("Changing value of select element to 'Rock'");
select.value = "Rock";

// Get the element with the "selected" attribute
console.log("Element with 'selected' HTML attribute: " + 
   select.querySelector("[selected]").getAttribute("value"));  // Still Blues!

// Get the element with the "selected" value:
console.log("But, value of the select element is now: " + select.value);  // Now Rock!

// Change which element has the selected attribute
console.log("Switching elment that has the 'selected' attribute...");
select.querySelector("[selected]").removeAttribute("selected");
select.querySelector("[value=Rock]").setAttribute("selected", "selected");

console.log("Element with 'selected' HTML attribute: " + 
  select.querySelector("[selected]").getAttribute("value"));
  
console.log(select.options[0])
console.log(select.options[1]);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="Rock">Storm</option>
  <option value="Blues" selected>Rain</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, all you need to do is set the desired option as selected. To get current `<select>` value one should look into the `select.value`:

```js
let select = document.body.querySelector('select'),
  newOption = new Option('Classic', 'Classic');

select.append(newOption);

select.options[2].selected = true;

console.log(select.value);
// Classic
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="Rock">Storm</option>
  <option value="Blues" selected>Rain</option>
</select>
```

Also note `selected` **attribute** only marks default selection, and is different than the `selected` property of the `<option>`. The attribute simply tells the browser if it should render the option as selected when initially drawing the DOM element or not.

---

When dealing with `<select multiple>`, you need to check the `.selectedOptions` property of the `<select>` and map it to an array. Example:

```js
let select = document.body.querySelector('select'),
  newOption = new Option('Classic', 'Classic');

select.append(newOption);

select.options[2].selected = true;

let values = [].slice.call(select.selectedOptions).map(a => a.value);
console.log(values)


// ["Blues","Classic"]
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="Rock">Storm</option>
  <option value="Blues" selected>Rain</option>
</select>
```

The [`.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) is an object which contains the selected options, the `length` and native methods, such as `item()` and `namedItem()`. Do note option groups are not contained.