# Change the selected option in select with only javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I'm trying to change the selected option of a select, I have already tried this way:

```
document.getElementById("myselect").value = "1";

and also 

document.getElementById("myselect").selectedIndex = 1;
```

but with the first one, it doesn't work, instead of changing to the option with the value 1, it goes to the last option of the select, and with the second one it doesn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programatically select an HTML option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-programatically-select-an-html-option-using-javascript) or [HTML SELECT - Change selected option by VALUE using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265596/html-select-change-selected-option-by-value-using-javascript) or [How to change the current selected option in the <select> by JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573650/how-to-change-the-current-selected-option-in-the-select-by-js)

Comment: Can you add the HTML code in the question description please? The first solution you've given looks right although I couldn't know for sure until I see the HTML

Comment: or [set option "selected" attribute from dynamic created option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `value` and `selectedIndex` but the usage is different, check the example below to understand how to use them.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select");
const options = document.querySelectorAll("select option");

// Using selectedIndex
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nextIndex = select.selectedIndex + 1;
  select.selectedIndex = nextIndex % options.length;
});

// Using value
document.getElementById("orange-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  select.value = "orange";
});
```

```html
<select value="apple" id="select">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Next Option</button>
<button id="orange-btn">Select Orange</button>
```

Comment: No, is not working, in my select, the option I want to set has the value "1" by the way, tried the code you sent me, and no.. any idea?

Comment: Whatever is the `value` of your option you need to set `.selected` to the same. I can help only if you add your HTML code in your question @alexcr.

Comment: here is the javascript: const select_u = document.getElementById("select_unit");

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(){
select_u.value = "1";
}

Comment: I have also tried: select_u.selectedIndex = 1; still no

Comment: @alexcr You need to share your code, it should work, you might be making some mistake.

Comment: I'm a bit character limited here so can't write it all, but here is the html, mainly: <select id="select_unit"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option> </select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset">

Comment: @alexcr Don't put it here in the comment put it in the question!